# JsTree - Disable and Enable checkboxes on select limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jstree

I have a jstree with few nodes. It is rendering fine. In addition to this I would like to have few more options.

1. If selected nodes is greater than n (say 5), then all other un selected checkbox-es should become disabled and should say hover message "Maximum number of 5".
2. If try to de-select any of the selected 5 nodes, the all the checkbox-es should be available for selecting again. Hover message should be hidden in this case.

Following is the [code pen for my Jstree implementation](https://codepen.io/JGSpark/pen/NmKoJL?editors=1010) so for...

What I need to do are,

```
1. Get the unselected nodes on hover condition if selected > 5, and disable all the unselected nodes with the css style

    cursor: not-allowed !important;  
    opacity: 0.4 !important;


Plus show the hover message "maximum of 5 reports".

2. If click on any selected nodes, then check if maximum 5 reached, enable all the unselected nodes remove the above css and allow the selected node to de-select.
```

Any idea to do this on event function?? Or Tree rendering ?? I am little bit confused currently. I have searched lot of questions in SO. But each one is different case.

Can anyone help me ??